# Using npm to install file to /usr/local/bin

Tags: permissions, cron, npm

I tried to install a file using the following command:

```
npm install -g price-feeder
```

It's supposed to be installed in the `/usr/local/bin` folder since it's using the global parameter to be accessible from a cron job. For some reason it's being installed in the following location though:

```
/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/
```

Any idea if there is a setting or something that would need to be set for the global parameter to install in the correct place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To see `npm` current prefix value in effect, run:

```
npm get prefix
```

As described in [install-and-configure-nodejs-and-npm-properly-on-ubuntu](https://medium.com/@vdeturckheim/install-and-configure-nodejs-and-npm-properly-on-ubuntu-16837d02ecaa)

You can set `npm` `prefix` e.g.:

```
$  npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

Note: [Official NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders.html) specify that:

> When in global mode, executables are linked into `{prefix}/bin` on Unix

Hence, your `npm prefix` shouldn't include the `/bin` suffix

In order to install in a system folder (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`) you should execute `npm` as `root` using `sudo`, e.g.:

```
sudo npm install -g price-feeder
```

Comment: And then read up on the issues associated with running tools like this as root: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4938592/1531971

Comment: @Yaron  I created a user and disabled root login etc, is there a way to run it as a root user from my created user?

Comment: @Yaron Also, when I did this I got an error: checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib. When I did the npm get prefix it showed me the /usr/local path without the big as you pointed out but now looking at the lib folder instead of bin by the looks of it

Comment: @user1048676 - in Ubuntu you don't need to use the user `root`, you can prefix `sudo` to your commands (assuming that your user holds the relevant permissions - which I assume is the case in your case) - did you try the running command in my answer `sudo npm install -g price-feeder` ?

Comment: @Yaron I got the message: sudo: npm: command not found. So I did sudo apt-get install npm but still getting the same error: checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib

Comment: I got it figured out. Accepting your answer. Thanks